# Finding n for amortization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I have this formula for amortization

PMT = PV * (i / (1 - (1+ i)^(-n) ) )

I'm having issues isolating n in cases where I'm given the present value, the payment value, and the interest rate, but not n.

Let's say I have:

PV = $800
i = 0.015
PMT = 51.04

I'm trying to solve for n as follows:

51.04 = 800 * (0.015 / (1 - (1.015)^(-n) ) )

0.0638 = 0.015 / (1 - (1.015)^(-n) )

ln(0.0638) = ln(0.015) - ln(1 - (1.015)^(-n) )

ln(0.0638) - ln(0.015) = - ln(1 - (1.015)^(-n) )

I have no idea what to do with ln(1 - (1.015)^(-n) ) to be quite frank, or if I'm even on the right track with that, I feel I'm missing something basic. However, in this case, I know n is equal to 18, but I have 0 idea how to get to that.

Comment: Try to isolate the term  1-(1+i)^(-n) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 
$$PMT=\frac {iPV}{1-(1+i)^{-n}}\\
1-(1+i)^{-n}=\frac {iPV}{PMT}\\
1-\frac {iPV}{PMT}=(1+i)^{-n}\\
\log\left(1-\frac {iPV}{PMT}\right)=-n\log(1+i)\\
-\frac{\log\left(1-\frac {iPV}{PMT}\right)}{\log(1+i)}=n$$